# XDEBUG_PATH_EXCLUDE in xdebug.ini

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-3

I have a setup with CentOS where xdebug 3 is installed.

As we are having problems with our umask for PHP processes with have in the php.ini added an umask.php file with `auto_prepend_file`, when triggering XDEBUG this file is of course hit as first, but have no mapping locally.

I have looked into the option: `XDEBUG_PATH_EXCLUDE` where I could add the path to the umask file, but here we have a chicken egg problem, because I cannot exclude it before it's already loaded.

Does an option exist to exclude it within the xdebug.ini file? I haven't found any indication that this option exists, but it doesn't mean that it's case.

Comment: Why not make `umask.php` file locally (even if it's empty, just have `<?php` there or even without it) for your IDE path mapping purposes? The IDE does not execute the actual script, it only uses it to see if request is "valid enough" so it can continue with the execution/debugging session in actual "proper files.

Comment: I know. But as I'm part of a bigger development team every person would need to do that. Everyone can do so if they get to annoyed by it. But as Derick mentioned, better look for the root of the problem instead of patching.

Comment: I 100% agree: it's better to solve original issue / root of the problem. I just thought: if it's only one person that faces this / no idea how to solve the original issue then such workaround definitely worth considering. I hope you will manage to fix it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XDEBUG_PATH_EXCLUDE` is only used with [`xdebug_set_filter`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_set_filter), which can filter out files for code coverage or stack traces only, and not for debugging.

Even if you **could** add it in an ini file (you can't), it wouldn't do anything.

I would recommend that you find out how to solve your original problem, *"As we are having problems with our umask for PHP processes..."*, instead of coming up with a "hack" to change the umask with an auto prepend file.

Comment: Thanks for a blasting fast reply. I am also going for that option, but was hoping for a "fix" till then.